# vlookup like function with awk

Tags: awk

1st tab separated file1:

```
chr1    10031   10031   ->      chr1    10061   10061
chr1    10037   10037   ->      chr1    10047   10047
chr1    10043   10043   ->      chr1    10053   10053
chr1    10055   10055   ->      chr1    10065   10065
```

2nd tab separated file2:

```
#Chr    Start   End     Ref     Alt     X
chr1    10031   10031   T       C       0
chr1    10037   10037   T       C       2.601e-05 
chr1    10043   10043   T       C       1.168e-05
```

Expected separated value table is:

```
chr1    10061   10061   T       C       0
chr1    10047   10047   T       C       2.601e-05 
chr1    10053   10053   T       C       1.168e-05
```

I will try that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$2]=$2; b[$3]=$3; next } { if ($2 in a && $3 in b) print $1, a[$3], b[$3], $4, $5, $6 }' file1 file2
```

But i cant. What is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: You're right, @EdMorton . If I had explained the problem better, it could have been solved in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Not just that but you may have had a completely different problem than the accepted answer solves, e.g. maybe your script actually worked (or partially worked) and you had DOS line endings or some other issues. A statement of in what way it didn't work would have eliminated some possible problems from consideration. Anyway, now you know for next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intend to get `$5,$6,$7` from file1 but are only storing `$2` and `$3` in your associative arrays.

You may use this `awk` instead:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
{
   k = $1 FS $2 FS $3
}
NR == FNR {
    map[k] = $5 FS $6 FS $7
    next
}
k in map {
   print map[k], $4, $5, $6
}' file1 file2

chr1    10061   10061   T   C   0
chr1    10047   10047   T   C   2.601e-05
chr1    10053   10053   T   C   1.168e-05
```

Comment: In this case `FS` and `OFS` are the same, but in case you have a different `FS` and `OFS` when setting `map[k]` you should use `OFS`

Comment: For using different values for `FS` and `OFS` use it like: `BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS=","}`

Comment: I meant, if you have different values for `FS` and `OFS` if you register `map[k] = $5 FS $6 FS $7` then when you'll print it you will have the wrong field separator. You should register it using `OFS` like `map[k] = $5 OFS $6 OFS $7`

Comment: ah yes good point @Marius_Couet